# Weird behavior when adding Strings to a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am experiencing this weird behavior when loading assets from external storage, sometimes the path gets added to the list and most of the time the path is not added.

Here is my function, Am I missing something?

```
Future<List<String>> loadAssets() async {
    List<String> loadedAssets = [];
    loadedAssets.add('test');
    try {
      final Directory dir = await syspath.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      dummyData.forEach((path) async {
        final extPath =
            path.substring(('assets/products_dummy_data/'.length));
            final localPath='${dir.path}/$extPath}';
        final file = File(localPath);
        if (await file.exists()) {
          await file.delete();
        }
        final data = await rootBundle.load(path);
        var asUint8List =
            data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
        await file.create(
          recursive: true,
        );
        await file.writeAsBytes(asUint8List);
        if (await file.exists()) {
          loadedAssets.add(localPath);
        }

      });

    } catch (e, s) {
      AppHelper.appLogger.e('Error while loading assets', e, s);
    }
    AppHelper.appLogger.i('loadedAssets.length ${loadedAssets.length}');
    return loadedAssets;
  }
```

But I always get the length as one, for the test element added

Comment: Problem Fixed after using  await Future.forEach

Comment: Please share the solution as a self answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Fixed after using await Future.forEach